# Use micro-ecc generated raw secp256k1 public key in C# to generate a shared secret on the server

Tags: aes, ecdh

I plan to use the `micro-ecc` **C** code on my `microcontroller-based` end unit to create a `uECC_secp256k1` public and private keys pair.

When connecting to a C# server, it will receive the server's raw 64-byte public key and send back to the server the end unit's raw 64 bytes public in order to reconstruct a common shared secret that will be used for AES256 encryption of messages while connected.

I want to send the keys in raw format since I do not want split IP packets. My communications protocol can handle raw binary data.

I tried using the **C#** `BouncyCastle` library but do not see how I can convert my 64 `byte[]` array into an `ECPublicKeyParameters` variable in order to reproduce the `AES256` key.

Comment: Please show us your actual code, rather than just giving a description.